# How we can implement a Material Showcase like views on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, material-design, showcaseview

I tried to develop a [Material Showcase](https://github.com/aromajoin/material-showcase-ios) implementation on SwiftUI using ZStacks. I tried the code below.

I've used the GeometryGetter view from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733037/7052287) to measure the content's rect parameters. Then using its midX, midY, width, and height, I set spotlight circles position and size.

The first problem, as shown in the code, is that it doesn't run `ShowcaseView` for more than one object.

Also, It doesn't position objects and spotlights correctly when the view hierarchy gets bigger and more complex.

Please let me know if you found the solution or used another approach for this purpose.

```
import SwiftUI

struct GeometryGetter: View {
  @Binding var rect: CGRect
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { (g) -> Path in
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.rect = g.frame(in: .global)
      }
      return Path()
    }
  }
}

struct ShowcaseView<Content : View> : View {
  
  @State private var animate = false
  @State private var rect = CGRect()
  
  var content: Content
  
  init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      
      Circle()
        .fill(Colors.primaryOrange)
        .frame(width: rect.width*2)
        .position(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
      
      ZStack {
        Circle()
          .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.05))
          .frame(width: rect.width * 1.25)
          .position(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
          .animation(nil)
          .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0)
          .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
        Circle()
          .fill(Color.white.opacity(0.10))
          .frame(width: rect.width * 1.5)
          .position(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
          .animation(nil)
          .scaleEffect(self.animate ? 1 : 0)
          .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
      }
      .onAppear {
        self.animate.toggle()
      }
      
      content
        .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $rect))
      
      
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  }
}

struct ShowcaseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    VStack {
      ShowcaseView {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
          Text("Search..")
          Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Colors.primaryBlue)
        .cornerRadius(25)
      }
      ShowcaseView {
        Text("Hello, World!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Material Showcase Example] ***vs*** [image: My Implemented Version of Material Showcase with SwiftUI]

Comment: did make any progress on this?

Comment: I'm very interested too. I wrote an issue to their Github repository. If you are interested too, please write a comment there! https://github.com/aromajoin/material-showcase-ios/issues/155
;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm more than happy if you find a better way to do that.
Anyway, I think this is an easy way to reach the goal. I did it in this way:

```
....

@State private var rect = CGRect.zero

var body: some View {
    ....
    // Component you want to showcase
    HStack {
        ...
    }
    .overlay(
        Color.clear.modifier(GeometryGetterMod(rect: $rect))
    )
    ...
}

func startShowcase(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Start Help Tour
    let showcase = MaterialShowcase()
    let uiview = UIView()
    uiview.frame = rect
    uiview.layer.cornerRadius = 45
    showcase.setTargetView(view: uiview)
    showcase.show(completion: {
        print("Showcase completion!")
    })
}

....

// Modifier to get the frame of your component
struct GeometryGetterMod: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return GeometryReader { (g) -> Color in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // to avoid warning
                self.rect = g.frame(in: .global)
            }
            return Color.clear
        }
    }
}
```

You can apply an overlay with a transparent color and a `GeometryGetterMod` in order to save the frame of your component in a `@State` variable for every component you want to showcase.
Just call startShowcase method passing the right variable like this:

```
startShowcase(rect)
```

Feel free to improve this method!