# SwiftUI - How to get GeometryReader size/height from different View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometryreader

How can I access the size of a View from another View?

To get the height of the "**Hello world!**" text, I attached a `.background()` of `GeometryReader` to it. For now, I'm just printing the height using `let _ = print(proxy.size.height)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world!")
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear /// placeholder
                        let _ = print(proxy.size.height) /// 20.333333333333332
                    }
                )
            
            Text("Height of first text is ???")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: "Hello world!" above "Height of first text is ???"]

I now want to replace `???` with the height of the "**Hello world!**". How can I do this?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59733037/14351818

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. Make a `@State` property to store the height
2. Set it using an `.onAppear {` attached to `Color.clear`
3. Replace `???` with `\(textHeight)`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textHeight = CGFloat(0) /// 1.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world!")
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear { /// 2.
                                textHeight = proxy.size.height
                            }
                    }
                )
                                          /// 3.
            Text("Height of first text is \(textHeight)") 
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: "Hello world!" above "Height of first text is 20.333333"]

Comment: `onAppear` is only called when it appears, so it doesn't handle orientation changes.

Comment: I spoke to an Apple engineer during WWDC21 and they said that to handle orientation, attach a `.onChange`.